# NTP sync time frequently on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ntp

I have several Win7 64bit configurations - local dev machine, remote server, VPS.
I'm running time sensitive tasks on all of them, therefore I need Windows Time service to:

- Sync
- Sync well         (<30ms)
- Sync frequently (once per minute)

Currently it doesn't do any of those...
I ***was*** able to do this on a Windows Server 2008 VPS using [these registry tweaks](https://superuser.com/questions/308104/ntp-sync-on-windows-server-2008), however it doesn't seem to work for Win7.

So... How do I sync time on Win7? well? frequently?

Comment: did you have any luck with [@JdeBP's](http://superuser.com/questions/308163/ntp-sync-doesnt/308178#308178) advice? I'd say he was spot on.

Comment: If time sync is very important to you and you have several machines then I strongly suggestion you setup one of your boxes to be a local NTP server.  Do not have every computer hitting the outside world.

Comment: From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Microsoft_Windows -- However, the Windows Time Service cannot maintain the system time more accurately than about a 1-2 second range.

Comment: @Michael - I haven't had much luck with JdeBP's advice. I think his links are Windows Server 2008 related and I don't know if they are applicable for Win7

Comment: @Zoredache - the machines are in different places in the world. On Win Server 2008 I was able to maintain 30ms accuracy most of the time with the registry tweaks I linked to.

Comment: An NTP server is probably the way to go, but for interest sake, to modify the update interval on Windows 7: Set `SpecialPollInterval`, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient` to a time in seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the default Windows capabilities/programmability does not meet your requirement, then you might consider any one of the many numerous time synchronization utilities available. There is a good chance that there are multiple utilities which can meet your requirements.

Comment: I agree here.  Particularly if you need 30ms or better accuracy.  The Built in Windows sync just isn't that great.  There are full NTP daemons that will run under windows.  http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm

Comment: @Zoredache - THAT link was a lifesaver. Why not write it as an answer? Who knows, I might accept it ;)